# Access length of nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Have an array containing an object which contains more arrays. How can the length of the nested arrays be accessed with .length?

```
const array = [ { var: [ 'asd', 'a3', 'a4' ], 
                  bar: [ 'asd', 'c3', 'c4' ] } ];
```

When using `array[0].var.length;`
if for example var[] only contains 1 attribute, it start measuring the string character length of the attribute. The number i'm after is the number of attributes not string length. If there are more than 1 attribute inserted then it measures the the number of attributes as it should.

Comment: Is this JavaScript? Please add proper tags.

Comment: is it dynamic or the properties and nesting level is already known/fixed?

Comment: for current code, you can simply use `array[0].var.length` and `array[0].bar.length`, both return 3

Comment: The strange thing is that if for example var[] only contains 1 attribute, it start measuring the string character length of the attribute. The number i'm after is the number of attributes not string length. If there are more than 1 attribute inserted then it measures the the number of attributes as it should.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one `object` in the `array`, you can use `for in` loop to iterate over the properties of the `object` and get the array associated with each key.

```js
const array = [
                { 
                   var: [ 'asd', 'a3', 'a4' ], 
                   bar: [ 'asd', 'c3', 'c4' ]
                } 
              ];


for(let key in array[0]) {
  console.log(array[0][key].length);
}
```

If you have more than one objects in the `array` and those objects in turn have variable number of arrays in them, you can use a combination of `for of` and `for in` loop to get the lengths of all the arrays inside all the nested objects.

```js
const array = [
                { 
                  var: [ 'asd', 'a3', 'a4' ], 
                  bar: [ 'asd', 'c3', 'c4' ]
                } 
              ];

for(let arrayItem of array) {
  for(let key in arrayItem) {
    console.log(arrayItem[key].length);
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting the same result as mentioned in the edit. If the nested array only contains 1 item then it measures the number of chars in the string, if  more than 1 item, then it measures number of items correctly.

Comment: `If the nested array only contains 1 item then it measures the number of chars in the string` no it doesn't. It measures the length of the array associated with each key in the nested object.

Comment: Thats what happens in my code for some reason

Comment: Code I posted doesn't have this problem. You haven't posted your code so I can't tell you what's wrong in your code. Try using the code I posted